Please help me ffmpeg and ffprobe update
Should I use XUI.one for ffmpeg 7.0 version?
Does that ffmpeg 7.0 version support the XUI.one?
I am using XUI Dashboard to use ffmpeg.
I upgraded the ffmpeg version to 7.0.
However, testing cannot be performed on the XUI dashboard.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
